# Perpendicular lines in three dimensions

Tags: geometry

If a line , say, in the z axis , is said to be perpendicular to the x-y plane , does it imply that any line  drawn on the x-y plane will be perpendicular to the given line ?

Comment: Yes, provided that "perpendicular" does not imply "intersecting" in your definition. The directions they point will be at right angles to on another.

Comment: @John thank you , so you mean to say that apart from the lines on the x y plane that intersect the given line , the lines of the x-y plane and the given line on the z axis will be skew lines , basically

Comment: Any vector $\boldsymbol{k}$ is said to be perpendicular to a vector $\boldsymbol{z}$ if $$\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{z} = 0 $$

Comment: @ja72 thank you but I just wanted to clarify that if a line is perpendicular to the x-y plane will it be perpendicular to all lines drawn on the plane even if it does not intersect them ?

Comment: @Aditi Well, two skew lines can either be perpendicular or not. As ja72 implies, the dot product is a way to see that "computationally." But you can think of it purely geometrically: if you translate one line to a parallel line that meets the other, are those two perpendicular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed in parametric form

- $z$ axis is defined by $t(0,0,1)$
- a line in $x-y$ plane has form $(x_0,y_0,0)+t(a,b,0)$

and the dot product of the direction vectors is

$$(0,0,1)\cdot (a,b,0)=0$$

thus they always are orthogonal.

Comment: Okay thank you again ! :)

Comment: You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. These are called Skew Lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines